# Use jquery to check if *any* fields have a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Starting with something like this

```
    $('#report-form').submit( function(){
    if ( ! $('#datetime, :checkbox, :radio, textarea').val() ){
            alert('not posted');
            return false;
        } else  {
            alert('posted');
        }

} );
```

Except that instead of not posting if any of the fields are empty, *I want it to post unless **all** of the listed fields/field-types are empty*. Is there a way of doing this with a selector string and not checking every item manually?

I thought of running an .each() function that increments a variable when it's blank and have it submit only if the # is less than the # of fields, but ideally I'm looking for something more generic (that will work with checkboxes and radio buttons as well as text inputs and text areas).

Comment: why dont you use something like jquery validate ?

Comment: what about $('#datetime, :checkbox, :radio, textarea').each()???

Comment: Had a quick look through the validate documentation and didn't notice a built in way to check 'at least one field must be filled'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.grep` to return an Array of elements that meet a condition.

Here if any element has a value, it will return `true` from the callback, and the `length` will be at least `1`, coercing to `true`.

```
var any = !!$.grep($('#datetime, :checkbox, :radio, textarea'), function(el) { 
    return !!el.value;
}).length;

if (any) {
    // there was at least one
}
```

---

Another possibility is using the *attribute-not-equals-selector*, though I wouldn't recommend it.

```
if (!!$('input[value!=""]').length)
```

It claims to check the attribute, but seems to actually check the `.value` *property*. This seems buggy to me. Since the docs claim that checks the attribute, I'd probably avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all of the inputs and textareas you want and set a variable to `true` (that's originally set to `false`) and break the loop when it encounters an input that's not empty.  Then you just check whether the variable is true or not after the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [valid()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) to invoke the validator directly.

```
$("#myform").validate();
$("a.check").click(function() {
    alert("Valid: " + $("#myform").valid());
    return false;
});
```